# Upload de multiplas imagens na mesma coluna db começa com vírgula

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

O registro no db está começando com uma vírgula.

O código começa com:

```
$imagens_nome ="";
foreach($_FILES as $file)....
```

Realiza o upload e cria thumbnail... Gera um novo nome : $NovoNome

e então antes de gravar no db:

```
 $imagens_nome = $imagens_nome.",".$NovoNome;
```

No entanto acho que a parte acima $imagens_nome... está errada, pois no db fica assim: coluna fotos: ,7263273813.jpg,737862834.jpg,236276322.jpg

Comment: Parece que tem um replace que troca pontos por vírgulas.

Comment: o código `$imagens_nome = $imagens_nome.",".$NovoNome;` aparenta estar correto. Afinal, os nomes estão sendo concatenados. Não dá pra ver no código exposto, como é feito o `$NovoNome` que é quem está, aparentemente, gerando o erro. Mostre mais código pra podermos ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi o único problema é que está indo com uma vírgula a mais por causa a sua forma de concatenação, certo?
Uma forma de resolver isso é fazer uma nova string começando do segundo caracter, pois o primeiro é sempre uma vírgula, isso antes de gravar no bd. Dessa forma:

```
<?php
$imagens_nome = ",7263273813.jpg,737862834.jpg,236276322.jpg";
$imagens_nome=substr($imagens_nome,1,strlen($imagens_nome));
?>
```

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer dúvida, só comentar...